# Body height scroll bars

Tags: html, css

I have a webpage like [this](http://mk7vrlist.altervista.org/databases/american_mobile.html) that contains a table and it is bigger that the screen size. So I have to put a vertical scroll bar.

I have an android device that opens webpages. I can see the table but I cannot scroll it (on android). When I open the page on firefox using my laptop I see the scroll bars and I can scroll it.

```
html{
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  min-height: 100%;
}
```

I wrote this code at the beginning of the page. How can I correctly setup scroll bars so I can scroll the page on my android app too?

I made a test and the problem is not about my android app, because I can scroll other website pages.

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cuggp/) HTML code of the page

Comment: Give you height in px

Comment: try adding overflow:scroll; in your css.

Comment: in your body container

Comment: it worked, make it as answer so I'll +1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

add

```
overflow:scroll;
```

in your body container.

Comment: can you plzz tick it as an answer?

Comment: I have to wait 5 minutes but I will ;)